# Google Maps fling event

Tags: android, google-maps, onfling

Is there any way to disable fling gesture on google map (SupportMapFragment)? Or I need at least an event to detect when map scrolling ends after fling and to compute map camera location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `OnCameraIdleListener`. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener):

> **onCameraIdle()**
>
> Called when camera movement has ended, there are no pending animations and the user has stopped interacting with the map

Thake into account that `OnCameraIdleListener` is one of the events that replace the deprecated `OnCameraChangeListener` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnCameraChangeListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener))).

You can get the new camera position like this:

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
}
```

You can know whether the user initiated the camera update event if you use the `OnCameraMoveStartedListener`. The method `onCameraMoveStarted(int reason)` provides a reason that equals `REASON_GESTURE` if the update has been initiated by the user. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener)

> **onCameraMoveStarted(int reason)**
>
> Called when the camera starts moving after it has been idle or when the reason for camera motion has changed.